# context:property-placeholder not resolving @Value

Tags: java, spring

I'm loading a property file this one var:

```
host=localhost
```

I'm loading it via XML like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/properties/config.properties"/>
```

The file loads fine (no errors).

I'm trying to resolve the property with @Value like so:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Value("${host:default}")
    private String host;

}
```

But 'host' always resolves to "default" i.e. it isn't finding it in the properties file I am loading. Is there something further I need to do? Based on some research, this should be enough to resolve properties the property-placeholder.

Comment: Quick guess... You have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and a `DispatcherServlet` in your `web.xml`. Both load an xml file which contain the same `<context:component-scan />`.

Comment: @M.Deinum your "quick guess" was spot on. Thanks.